# Regain focus after flyout closed in a Store App

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a flyout page which I use to login. I store the username in the localsettings and its all fine up to this point. After the login I want the pagetitle of the page to be something like: "welcome: " + username. (where username is stored in the localsettings).

This works. But only after I reloaded the mainpage by for example going to another page and back again or when I close the entire app and start it again. It doesn't work right away after "login in" do to localsettings only being loaded when a page is started not when its already running.

**Is there a way to "reload" the mainpage after the flyout closes?** Is there something that I can execute when the mainpage gains focus? Might there be a method for regaining focus(if so I can't find it).

This is (a part of) my flyout page where i store the variables in my localsettings:

```
localSettings.Values["settingUserName"] = TbUserName.Text;
localSettings.Values["settingPassword"] = TbPassWord.Text;
```

*note : Frame.Navigate(typeof(page) does NOT work. since flyouts doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, ill share it here if anybody else ever needs it.
In C# store apps there is something that checks if the screen got focus. To add this method just add this to the code of the page you want to check if it has focus (or just gained focus).

```
protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }
```